# How to get result of working scrapy crawler as a variable, python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have approximately 11M urls which should be parsed and data should be extracted. I would like to do it with Scrapy Crawler.

Architecture that I have created have one file start_script.py with code:

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    spider_name = 'example'
    with open( 'file.csv', 'rb' ) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader( csvfile, delimiter = ',' )
        for link in reader:
            os.system('scrapy crawl %s -a link=%s -o %s -t csv' % ( spider_name, link, filename ) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and scrpay crawler.

I have to store result of parsing data plus additional information into file, the most effective way keep this file be opened and write into it.

Therefore, are there any way to get result of Scrapy Crawling into a variable from start_script.py file ? Maybe exist any other way to do it with usage scrapy ?

I have tried read scrapy documentation(http://doc.scrapy.org/).
I have tried search answers and related questions into StackOverflow(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?).
And of course the most common I have tried to find answer in Google(https://www.google.com).

As you may understand result is nothing!

Any answers, comments and ideas will be useful, please, keep in mind that I need to do it with usage of Scrapy or to be 100% sure that it is impossible.

Comment: it depends on the situation whether structures of all websites are same?? Are u going to cram all calculations into a single spider? one spider for one website?? Please, be specific towards ur work

Comment: I would like to scrap one website, many links are from the same website are.

Comment: ok, then why r u not using item pipeline?? Under your scrapy poject, u must have written the spider definition. right??? just use item pipeline to write ur scrapped results to CSV or JSON file.

Comment: Could you possibly provide me  any example how to write into csv file and I consider it may be solution ? Because I have tried figuring out how pipeline should be written, but still do not understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried till now?? post your spider definition source code.

Fine. Under your scrapy project a python file "pipelines.py" exists. Append the following code in this file:

```
import csv

class myExporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('filename.csv', 'wb'))
        self.myCSV.writerow(['field1', 'field2',...])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['field1'], item['field2'], item['field3'],...])

    return item
```

Now, open settings.py file and append following code:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['your_Project_Name.pipelines.myExporter']
```

Hope, this will work..!!! :)

Comment: I like this answer, but according to the post above I recommend use ITEM_PIPELINES = {'PROJECTNAME.pipelines.YourPipeline': 300}.

Unfortunately, it still is not an answer, because my problem that I need to close and open file everytime. What I really want is to have open file where I can write data, not only result of request, but also additional specific data. I need shell-like file to control this process. There are many tricky things in such architecture, therefore, if you still have any ideas, I will be happy to hear them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use CsvItemExporter to export data to csv with ease.**

In the items.py file :

```
    import scrapy
    class YourItem(scrapy.Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        # name = scrapy.Field()
        field1 = scrapy.Field()
        field2 = scrapy.Field()
        extradata = scrapy.Field()
```

In the pipelines.py file :

```
    from scrapy import signals
    from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
    class YourPipeline(object):
        def __init__(self):
            # Initialize PIPELINE 
            self.files = {}
            self.ids_seen = list()

        @classmethod
        def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
            pipeline = cls()
            crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
            crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
            crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_error, signals.spider_error)
            crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.item_dropped, signals.item_dropped)
            return pipeline

        def item_dropped(self,item, response, exception, spider):
            # ITEM dropped from pipeline


        def spider_error(self,failure, response, spider):
            # SPIDER encountered error

        def spider_opened(self, spider):
            # SPIDER opened 
            file = open('filename.csv', 'w+b')
            self.files[spider] = file
            self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
            self.exporter.start_exporting()

        def spider_closed(self, spider):
            # SPIDER closed
            self.exporter.finish_exporting()
            file = self.files.pop(spider)
            file.close()

        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            # Process ITEM
            if item['UNIQUEIDOFYOURCHOICE'] in self.ids_seen:
                raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
            else:
                self.ids_seen.append(item['UNIQUEIDOFYOURCHOICE'])
                self.exporter.export_item(item)
                return item
```

Activate your pipeline in settings.py

```
    ITEM_PIPELINES = {'PROJECTNAME.pipelines.YourPipeline': 300,}
```

The above pipeline will export to specified CSV file with the item field-names as headers as well as drop duplicates based on any unique key you wish to specify.(http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html?highlight=csvitemexporter)

To send data to pipeline from SPIDER:

```
    from items import YourItem

    for VALUE in SETOFVALUES:
        item = YourItem()
        item['field1'] = 'SOME VALUE'
        item['field2'] = 'SOME VALUE2'
        item['extradata'] = 'SOMEEXTRADATA'
        # yield WILL SEND THE ITEM WITH DATA CURRENTLY ASSIGNED TO IT TO PIPELINE
        yield item
```